# Bootstrap modal x button out of position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting up a Boostrap modal and what I've put below is fairly basic code, but the x close button on the modal is out of position. The button is sitting down lower than the vertical center of the div.

I can't see anywhere that this might be affected?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Monsta Desk</title>

    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      });
    </script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put it inside your h5 element

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
    </h5>

  </div>
```

Comment: But my code comes straight from the Boostrap demo page.

Comment: Yeah, and it's wrong on the demo page. Things happen.

Answer (score 2):

Move the button ahead of the modal-title div
Try this

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Monsta Desk</title>


    <!-- jQuery -->



    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  </head>
  <body>


    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(window).on('load',function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: But my code comes straight from the Boostrap demo page.

Answer (score 0):

> Add an internal style of width like the code below, it worked for me.

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="width:20px;
×